# How to solve the following unique finding issue?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary of `<int, bool>,`

like `1, false; 2 true;... ; 9 true;`

I need to find if there is a unique one.

For example, if all except 9 are false, I can output 9

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are the keys consecutive integers?

Comment: You can group by the values (treated as an IEnumerable) and check the number of keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by `Value` and get the group that has one item:

```
var result = dictionary
            .GroupBy(x => x.Value) 
            .First(g => g.Count() == 1) // get the group
            .First().Key; // get the first pair in the group and it's key
```

This will throw exception if there is no unique value, to prevent this you can use:

```
var result = dictionary
            .GroupBy(x => x.Value) 
            .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Count() == 1);

if(result != null)
{
    var value = result.First().Key;
}
```

Comment: so powerful! The first time I saw the power of Linq. For novice question, if there is no such item, what will be the result, NULL?

Comment: is there a way to avoid exception?

Comment: like get a Boolean, then if true, get the key? Seems clumsy

Comment: Fantastic! to get deeper, what the type for result, another dictionary?

Comment: it should be `IGrouping<bool, KeyValuePair<int,bool>>`

Comment: btw in my last comment I miss that GroupBy returns IGrouping. so you can use FirstOrDefault and check for null. but as I said you still need a check.anyway I changed my code to use this approach, because this is more elegant, it will perform the grouping only once instead of twice

Comment: let me try tonight and report the result. Looks promising now. ^_^

Comment: tried with your answer, it works, so good. Could you add using FirstOrDefault to the answer, I am not sure I get your point.

Comment: If I need not only unique value, but also unique specific value, like unique false, how to change?